# Tor Browser SWF socket

Tags: anonymity, javascript, chrome

I used Tor with Chrome in anonymous mode.

I used a webmail and I send a mail with an uploaded file.

I found the following code:

`"ndex","mailUploadServiceUrl":"/neo2/handlers/upload_attachment.jsx", "websocketSwfUrl":"//yastatic.net/mail/neo2/9.21.11/static/swf/web-socket.swf", "version":"9.21.11","version_full":"9.21.11-0","date":"04.02.2015", "xivaHost":"push.yandex.com","metricaID":"1143050", "showWizardUntil":"1331064000000","social-"`

Is my real IP address revealed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

When you are using Flash (swf files), you are letting the door to your anonymity wide open. Flash can see your IP address and reveal it to the hosting site, thus de-anonymizing you.

Furthermore, consider using an open-source browser such as Firefox or TorBrowser. They are safer than closed-source browsers such as Google Chrome, and they don't have a potential of carrying secret backdoors for spying on you.

Answer (score 0):

Flash and other plugins offer a whole new attack surface and therefor should not be used in combination with Tor.

Instead I highly recommend using the official [Tor Browser](https://www.torproject.org/download/download-easy.html.en) (which is not just Firefox, even though it is based on it) for browsing the web. Next to your example it prevents many other forms of attacks that could reveal your identity.